# Populating RecyclerView with JSON in Xamarin

Tags: android, json, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I recently switched .. or at least am trying to switch from using ListViews to the more efficient RecyclerView. I am trying to populate my RecyclerView using JSON data, most of the tutorials I've found use static data. Does anyone have an idea of how this can be achieved ? Im not getting any errors when i build, my app even runs! I also triple checked the JSON and it is definately being retrieved but there is no data being displayed...

Comment: You should also be posting your snippets to check what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make one method which will directly bind data inside your recyclerview.

in your main activity write..

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
Place place
adapter.addData(place)
}
```

in your adapter file...

```
List<Place> place = new ArrayList();

public void addData(Place place)
{
place.add(place)
notifyDataChanged();
}
```

Here note one thing that Place object is just an example. Put your json response object in place of that one.

Comment: Mrugesh, Thanks for the reply..My JSON is being deserialized using Newtonsoft.Json Library and the data is being stored in a List<MyClass>. With what you have given me, I'm assuming i have to add the data manually or through loop?

Comment: Mrugesh, Let me rephrase.. I am getting the data from a database via JSON, the data is deserialized and put in a List<MyClass> MyList datatype.. I am trying to display every element in this list..

Comment: you can do this with passing  List<MyClass> inside the method addData

Comment: If you do not want your adapter to initialize while being instantiated then you can define one separate method which will add the data.